# How to check if a class method returns self?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to list all methods from a given class that return `self`.

I am aware that in Python it is impossible to check what is the return type of a function before it was run.

Perhaps it would be possible to check for `return self` in the function body (source) or maybe there is some other way?

I need it to work with Python 3.5 and above

**EDIT:**

This class (not a full code) is a part of gremlinpython library.

```
class GraphTraversal(Traversal):
    def __init__(self, graph, traversal_strategies, bytecode):
        super(GraphTraversal, self).__init__(graph, traversal_strategies, bytecode)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, int):
            return self.range(long(index), long(index + 1))
        elif isinstance(index, slice):
            low = long(0) if index.start is None else long(index.start)
            high = long(sys.maxsize) if index.stop is None else long(index.stop)
            if low == long(0):
                return self.limit(high)
            else:
                return self.range(low,high)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Index must be int or slice")
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.values(key)

    def V(self, *args):
        self.bytecode.add_step("V", *args)
        return self

    def addE(self, *args):
        self.bytecode.add_step("addE", *args)
        return self

    def addV(self, *args):
        self.bytecode.add_step("addV", *args)
        return self
```

It allows to query the graph data base using fluent API like this

```java
g.V().hasLabel('label').has('id','xxx').addE('relation').to(g.V().hasLabel('otherlabel').has('id','yyy')
```

So far I was able to get the methods like this:

```
from inspect import getsourcelines, signature

def contains_return_self(f):   
   lines, _ = getsourcelines(f)   
   return any("return self" in line for line in lines)

def check_signature(f):
   sig = signature(f)
   if(len(sig.parameters) == 2 
      and 'self' in sig.parameters.keys()
      and 'args' in sig.parameters.keys()):
      return True
   return False

fluent_methods = [
   method_name for method_name in dir(GraphTraversal) 
      if callable(getattr(GraphTraversal, method_name)) 
         and ('__' not in method_name)
         and contains_return_self(getattr(GraphTraversal, method_name))
         and check_signature(getattr(GraphTraversal, method_name))]
```

I would like to return all the methods that have the following signature:

```
def foo(self, *args)
    # some code
    return self
```

Comment: Looks like you have a problem, and are trying to solve it in some way (in your case, trying to see which classes return `self`). However, it is very very likely that this is not the way to go.. So what you are asking us is a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and apparently every solution to this will be messy and have an awful design. Instead, why don't you post your original problem in the first place?

Comment: Why would methods return self in the first place? This is not a common thing to do in Python.

Comment: A `return self` statement does not mean that the instance is guaranteed to ever be returned and if it is missing it does not mean it is guaranteed to never be returned.

Comment: What if the function only sometimes returns self (for example in an `if`)?

Comment: @MSeifert These functions always return self. This is a part of a fluent interface.

Comment: @RafaelC: The problem is as follows: I have a class that is implementing a fluent interface. I want to list the possible operations defined. I can only tell that all these methods have the following signature def foo(self, *args): ..some code.. return self

Comment: @DanielRoseman: The class is not mine design. I need to simply query its fluent interface. All the methods are defined as def foo(self, *args): ..some code.. return self

Comment: @KlausD. Not sure if it is important. I simply need to tell what methods that match my query were defined in a given class

Comment: What exactly is your query? Python supports introspection, so it might be possible to do something based on the signatures of the class methods (but checking type of return value isn't possible).

Comment: @marineau According to the partial code I added, I would like to get list of function names in this case: V, addE, addV. These functions have all the same signature

Comment: @Sebastian: You misspelled my username in your last comment, so I didn't get notified about it (or would have responded more quickly). Anyway, when I run the code currently in your question, the value that ens up in `fluent_methods` is `['V', 'addE', 'addV']` — so it appears to already be doing what you want (except for checking the return value of the methods, which, as I and others have said, isn't possible to determine).

Comment: @martineau: Sorry for the typo, and thanks for your help. The class has much more methods and also inherits some from Traversal class. I would like to narrow the results as much as possible. Please check my last solution in the edits. This is probably very ugly solution but I have not got much experience in Python

Answer (score 1):

Although, like @RafaelC, I strongly suspect this is likely an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), here's something — based partially on the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#module-inspect) module — that seems to work (within the inherent limitations of such an approach). For testing I added a definition of the `Traversal` base class as well as some non-matching methods to both it and the derived `GraphTraversal` class.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import inspect
import re

class Traversal:
    def inherited_method1(self, *args):
        return self

    def inherited_method2(self, foobar):
        return foobar + 13

class GraphTraversal(Traversal):
    def __init__(self, graph, traversal_strategies, bytecode):
        super(GraphTraversal, self).__init__(graph, traversal_strategies, bytecode)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, int):
            return self.range(long(index), long(index + 1))
        elif isinstance(index, slice):
            low = long(0) if index.start is None else long(index.start)
            high = long(sys.maxsize) if index.stop is None else long(index.stop)
            if low == long(0):
                return self.limit(high)
            else:
                return self.range(low,high)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Index must be int or slice")

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.values(key)

    def non_match1(self, *args):
        self.bytecode.add_step("V", *args)
        return 42

    def non_match2(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.bytecode.add_step("V", *args)
        return self

    def V(self, *args):
        self.bytecode.add_step("V", *args)
        return self

    def addE(self, *args):
        self.bytecode.add_step("addE", *args)
        return self

    def addV(self, *args):
        self.bytecode.add_step("addV", *args)
        return self

### Introspect class
DUNDER = re.compile(r"^_{2,}\w*_{2,}\Z", re.UNICODE)
MethInfo = namedtuple('MethInfo', ['name', 'value'])

methods = [MethInfo(*pair) for pair in inspect.getmembers(GraphTraversal, inspect.isfunction)
                if not DUNDER.match(pair[0])]

def contains_return_self(meth_info):
    src = inspect.getsource(meth_info.value)
    for line in src.splitlines():
        if 'return self' in line.strip():
            return True
    else:
        return False

def check_signature(meth_info):
    sig = inspect.signature(meth_info.value)
    return str(sig) == '(self, *args)'

fluent_methods = [meth_info.name for meth_info in methods
                    if contains_return_self(meth_info) and check_signature(meth_info)]

print('fluent_methods:', fluent_methods)
```

Output:

```
fluent_methods: ['V', 'addE', 'addV', 'inherited_method1']
```